# Oracle SQL - multi-level correlated subquery does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to run an UPDATE statement with 2 levels of subqueries that refer to the updated table, but getting an error. 
Please consider the following code. It's giving me "c.end_date invalid identifier" error as if table c (the updated table) is not visible within the deepest subquery.
If I flatten the subqueries to only one level subquery I loose the logic behind it.

Any ideas on how to write this so it will compile and work correctly?

I'm using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Prod

```
create table calc(
  agrmt_id number,
  cust_num number,
  prod_id  number,
  price    number,
  start_date date,
  end_date   date);


create table trans(
  agrmt_id number,
  cust_num number,
  prod_id  number,
  units    number,
  trans_date date);

create table products(
  prod_id number,
  other_prc number,
  prod_start date,
  prod_end   date);

update calc c set price = (with avg_price_per_prod as (select prod_id, avg(other_prc) avg_prc 
                from products
               where prod_end  >= c.start_date
                 and prod_start <= c.end_date
               group by prod_id  
              ) select sum(t.units) * a.avg_prc           
             from trans t, avg_price_per_prod a
            where t.trans_date between c.start_date and c.end_date
              and t.agrmt_id=c.agrmt_id
              and t.cust_num=c.cust_num

              and t.prod_id = a.prod_id
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the updated table `c` within a sub-subquery (factored or otherwise). You'll have to eliminate it, maybe something like this (untested):

```
update calc c set price = (
    select sum(t.units) * avg(other_prc)
    from trans t, products p
    where t.trans_date between c.start_date and c.end_date
      and t.trans_date between p.prod_start and p.prod_end
      and t.prod_id = p.prod_id
      and t.agrmt_id=c.agrmt_id
      and t.cust_num=c.cust_num
)
```